# bad character regexp in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
1563:37say: 0 kl4|us: !!alias kl4
```

and I need to extract some information. I'm trying with this Python code:

```
 import re
 x = "1563:37say: 0 kl4us: !!alias kl4"
 res = re.search( r"(?P<say>say(team)?): (?P<id>\d+) (?P<name>\w+): (?P<text>.*)",x)

 slot= res.group("id")
 text = res.group("text")
 say = res.group("say")
 name = res.group("name")
```

This code works fine. Why if I have a character `|` or `*` into my string this regexp doesn't work?

For example:

```
 import re
 x = "1563:37say: 0 kl4|us: !!alias kl4"
 res = re.search( r"(?P<say>say(team)?): (?P<id>\d+) (?P<name>\w+): (?P<text>.*)",x)

 slot= res.group("id")
 text = res.group("text")
 say = res.group("say")
 name = res.group("name")
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Wessie The characters mentioned appear in the data, not the regex.

Answer (score 5):

Based on where you added the "|", it looks like you expect "|" and "*" to be matched by `\w`, but `\w` only matches letters, digits, and "_".  To match those characters as well, change the `\w` to `[\w|*]`:

```
res = re.search( r"(?P<say>say(team)?): (?P<id>\d+) (?P<name>[\w|*]+): (?P<text>.*)",x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for late. Your code works fine.
Thanks again